# Is there any specific validation mechanism in spring web framework

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jdbctemplate, spring-web

Well, with use of hibernate/JPA we can do the serverside data validation easily by using specific annotations in the model itself.
I'm just using JDBC template to access the dB. 
Is my option of data validation, checking each entry one by one for specificity or is there any spring feature that helps in data validation easily that I'm unaware of?

Answer (score 0):

You can always use **Hibernate validation** for this. You can annotate fields in your request objects from annotations in the `javax.validation.constraints.` spring will validate your request according to the annotation.

Answer (score 0):

For server side there is option for Hibernate Validators.Here https://www.journaldev.com/2668/spring-validation-example-mvc-validator is nice example to use that.

Otherwise after receiving the fields on the controller you can manually validate using regular expressions.
https://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/Java_Regexe.html

For client/front end validation you can use javascript/jquery validations. just have a look on jquery validate plugin.

https://jqueryvalidation.org/